# Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded in line 112 in chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas

I am trying to develop a canvas where one first uploaded image overlap with another image(second image) and resize and move it by dragging it. But its show the above error

> Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded in line 112

**Code:**

```
function drawImage(img, withAnchors, withBorders) {
// clear the canvas
ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
// draw the image
var view = img.view;
ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, img.width, img.height, view.left, view.top, view.width, view.height);//**This is line 112**

// optionally draw the draggable anchors
if (withAnchors) {
    drawDragAnchor(view.left, view.top);
    drawDragAnchor(view.left + view.width, view.top);
    drawDragAnchor(view.left + view.width, view.top + view.height);
    drawDragAnchor(view.left, view.top + view.height);
}

// optionally draw the connecting anchor lines
if (withBorders) {
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.rect(view.left, view.top, view.width, view.height);
    ctx.stroke();
}
draw(img, true, false);
}
```

Please help me to solve the this error.
I am Gladful if anyone help me out this issue.

Comment: That happens when recursive call occurs in your code.

Comment: Try to console all of your `drawImage` function `parameters`. Are you getting perfect values?

Comment: May be problem with `view.left, view.top, view.width, view.height` parameters. try to get static values like `100,100,100,100`.